# View calc and multiple field collection lines

Tags: views, entities

I came here because I have a problem with view calc module and several lines in my field collection. So first the result of my view look like this :

[image: My view]

All this fields are in the same content type, and I put `sum calculation` on each fields. But it's seems the value of the field is multiplied by the count of lines in my field collections. So for the first sum(Montant HT) the calcul done is :

8600 + 51600 + (3101.26 * 5) + 2962.99 + (42000 * 3)

For the column `paid sum` I don't know how the sum is calculated I doesn't understand.

I tried to use distinct but it didn't work, so how can I found the right sum for all my column ??

Thanks

Comment: Can I UP this post ?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found a way to make it work. Although, maybe it's not a good solution but it worked.
Here is steps:

1. Find file views_calc_table.inc in views_calc module directory.
2. Change `if ($query_alias == 'unknown') {` to `if ($query_alias ==
   'unknown' || $field->field_info['type'] == 'field_collection') {` in
   line 238 under `function add_aggregation_fields(&$view)`

**Remind，never hack core!**